# Get the first element after the first sequence of length N of consecutively increasing values

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I'm looking for an efficient way of extracting the first element after the first sequence of N consecutive elements in which the values are increasing.
If these are the data of a toy example:

```
data = {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 4}, {7, 6}, {8, 
   3}, {9, 4}, {10, 5}, {11, 6}, {12, 7}, {13, 8}, {14, 9}, {15, 10}};
```

and I would like to get the first element after the first sequence of 5 consecutive increasing values (from those in second position), I should obtain the row {13,8}.

I was playing around with:

```
Split[data, #2[[2]] > #1[[2]] &]
```

that groups my data in sequences of increasing values, but I wasn't able to find a way to add the additional constraints I need. Any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: You mean the first element of column 1 after the FIRST sequence of N consecutive increasing values in column 2?

Comment: @Rojo If we talk about columns and rows, I mean the first row after the first sequence of N consecutive increasing values in column 2. I edited the question.

Comment: Wouldn't in your example be {14,9} the answer? The increasing sequence is `{8,3}->{9,4}->{10, 5}->{11,6}->{12, 7}->{13,8}`, so the row after is `{14, 9}`?

Comment: @Rojo It depends on the definition. I'm fine with `{13,8}`.

Comment: My real question isn't 4 vs 5. It's more about: the result is the next row following the sequence or the last one on the sequence? If instead of `{13, 8}` you had `{13, -8}` would that row be your result?

Comment: @Rojo I'm going to use this to detect the onset of a movement from a velocity profile, the length sequence will be much longer, so it will be very unlikely that the first sequence of consecutive increasing values will be suddenly interrupted by a decreasing value. In any case, if this would happen neither of the two solutions (next following the sequence or last of the sequence) would detect the onset of the movement I'm looking for, since the decreasing value would indicate an anomalous break of the movement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following your first approach this satisfies your needs :

```
Select[Split[data, #2[[2]] > #1[[2]] &], Length @ # > 5 &][[All, 6]]
```

> ```
> {{13, 8}}
> ```

**Edit**

The OP was edited and now it asks for **the first element** after **the first sequence** of 5 consecutive increasing values...  Thus we can use [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html?q=Select&lang=en) with the third argument `n` to select the first `n` elements satisfying the criterion,  i.e. in our case (`n=1`) :

```
Select[ Split[ data, #2[[2]] > #1[[2]]& ], Length @ # > 5 &, 1][[All, 6]]
```

Comment: Nice one +1. I'd add 1 as the third argument to `Select` since he only seems to want the first. Careful however if he has a length 5 increasing sequence, you probably will get an error and you won't be finding the "next row" following the sequence

Comment: @Rojo Thanks, interesting remarks !  My solution doesn't produce an error even if there is no increasing sequence of length > 5 as your first method does. Anyway I like them both +1.

Comment: Yeah, no error in `{}[[All, 6]]`, I expected that wrongly. Mines both produce an error when there's no sequence

Answer (score 6):

Here is another try at a version that does not unpack; the first version was not quite right.

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray@{{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 
     6}, {6, 4}, {7, 6}, {8, 3}, {9, 4}, {10, 5}, {11, 6}, {12, 
     7}, {13, 8}, {14, 9}, {15, 10}};
(*data={{a,1},{b,2},{c,-2},{d,-1},{e,0},{f,3},{g,5},{h,6},{j,7},{k,8}}\
*)
ClearAll[select]
select[p_Integer] := 
 Compile[{{in, _Integer, 1}}, Module[{pos = 0, val = 0},
   Do[
    val += in[[i]];
    If[in[[i]] == 0, val = 0; Continue[]];
    If[val == p, pos = i; Break[];];
    , {i, Length[in]}];
   pos
   ]
  ]
On["Packing"]
cf = select[5];
res = UnitStep[data[[All, -1]] - RotateRight[data[[All, -1]]]];
data[[cf[res]]]
(* {13, 8} *)
```

Comment: I don't think this works correctly for other lists. Try `{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, -2}, {d, -1}, {e, 0}, {f, 3}, {g, 5}, {h, 6}, {j,7}, {k, 8}}`

Comment: @Rojo, yes, that first version was not quite right. It should be fixed with this version. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way, somewhat similar to Rojo's.

```
selectAfterN[data_, n_] := Pick[data, Accumulate /@ SplitBy@
    UnitStep[{0}~Join~Differences[data][[All, 2]]] // Flatten, n]

selectAfterN[data, 5]
(* {13, 8} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps

```
q = 5;

Transpose@data /. {_, index_} :> 
  First@Extract[data, 
    1 + Position[Flatten[Accumulate /@ Split@Sign@Differences@index], 
      q]]
```

An alternative, somewhat @Verde-ish, is

```
Replace[data, {___, 
   i : Repeated[{_, _}, {q}] /; 
    q - 1 == Total@Sign@Differences[{i}[[All, 2]]], n_, ___} :> 
  n]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Cases[{{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}, {e, 5}, {f, 6}, {g, 7}, {h, 8}}}, 
      {___, {_, a_}, {_, b_}, {_, c_}, {_, d_}, {_, e_}, {ff_, f_}, ___} /;
       a < b < c < d < e < f :> {ff, f}]

(*
-> {f,6}
*)
```

If you want to detect only sequences increasing by 1:

```
Cases[{{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}, {e, 5}, {f, 6}, {g, 7}, {h,8}}}, 
       {___, {_, a_}, {_, b_}, {_, c_}, {_, d_}, {_, e_}, {ff_, f_}, ___} /; 
       f == e + 1 == d + 2 == c + 3 == b + 4 == a + 5 :> {ff, f}]
```

If you want to stick with your StringSplit thing:

```
data = {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 4}, {7, 6}, {8, 3}, {9, 4}, 
        {10, 5}, {11, 6}, {12, 7}, {13, 8}, {14, 9}, {15, 10}};
(Select[#, Length@# > 5 &] &@Split[data, #2[[2]] > #1[[2]] &])[[All, 6]]

(*
-> {{13, 8}}
*)
```

Comment: I think I need an Alka-Seltzer to digest this one.

Comment: @VLC Your question is pretty simple, that's why you received so many answers. I stuck by Brian Kerninghan's advice: _http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103299/help-me-understand-this-brian-kernighan-quote_ So, don't be unthankful

Comment: I always like to see many variations on the theme, so I'm thankful to you and all the others. Some stuff is simply out of my reach now.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another route:

```
data = {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 4}, {7, 6}, {8, 3},
        {9, 4}, {10, 5}, {11, 6}, {12, 7}, {13, 8}, {14, 9}, {15, 10}};

With[{k = 5}, 
     data[[Total[TakeWhile[Length /@ SplitBy[Differences[data],
           Composition[Positive, Last]], # < k &]] + k + 1]]]
   {13, 8}
```

Using Verde's example:

```
data2 = {{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}, {e, 5}, {f, 6}, {g, 7}, {h, 8}}};

With[{k = 5}, 
     data2[[Total[TakeWhile[Length /@ SplitBy[Differences[data2],
           Composition[Positive, Last]], # < k &]] + k + 1]]]
   {f, 6}
```

Comment: The increment by 1 was just in my toy example. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @VLC, I've generalized the original routine.

Answer (score 2):

Using `NestWhile` and `OrderedQ`:

```
ClearAll[takeNextAfterTest];
takeNextAfterTest = Function[{data, num, col, comp},
    With[{temp = NestWhile[Rest, data, 
       (Length@# > num && !OrderedQ[#[[;; num, col]], comp]) &]},
    If[Length@temp == num, {}, temp[[1 + num]]]]];
```

Examples:

```
data2 = {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 4}, {7, 6}, {8, 3}, 
        {9, 4}, {10, 5}, {11, 6}, {12, 7}, {13, 8}, {14, 9}, {15, 10}, {8, 9}, 
        {9, 8}, {10, 7}, {11, 6}, {12, 5}, {13, 10}, {14, 10}, {15, 11}};

takeNextAfterTest[data2, 5, 2, Less]
(* {13, 8} *)
takeNextAfterTest[data2, 3, 2, #2 == 1 + #1 &]
(* {6, 4} *)
takeNextAfterTest[data2, 5, 2, Greater]
(*  {12,5} *)
takeNextAfterTest[data2, 2, 2, Equal]
(* {15, 11} *)
```

Using `NestWhile` and `Ordering`:

```
ClearAll[takeNextAfterOrderingPattern];
takeNextAfterOrderingPattern = Function[{data, num, col, orderedlike},
  With[{temp = 
    NestWhile[Rest, data,
     (Length@# > num && (Ordering[#[[;; num, col]]] =!= Ordering[orderedlike])) &]},
  If[Length@temp == num, {}, temp[[1 + num]]]]];
```

Examples:

```
takeNextAfterOrderingPattern[data2, 5, 2, Range[5]]
(* {13,8} *)
takeNextAfterOrderingPattern[data2, 5, 2, Range[5, 1, -1]]
(* {12,5} *)
takeNextAfterOrderingPattern[data2, 5, 2, {3, 4, 2, 4, 1}]  
(*  {9, 4} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Especially the `takeNextAfterTest` seems to be much faster than Artes solution.